# what kind of php tag is this

Tags: php

what tag is this and how does this execute ? I mean %content% tag

```
$body = str_replace('%content%', $leftcol, $template);
```

Comment: This is not a tag but a function, by typing http://php.net/str_replace in your browser's address bar you can get this function's description.

Comment: Also note that this whole line is very poor idea of template implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a PHP tag. The function only replaces the string `%content%` with the value of `$leftcol` in the `$template` variable. See http://php.net/str_replace for further help.

Answer (score 4):

It's a replace function. It changes '%content%' string in $template variable to the content of $leftcol variable.

```
$template = 'some text, some text, %content%';
$leftcol = 'new text';

$body = str_replace('%content%', $leftcol, $template);
```

$body is now:

> some text, some text, new text

Check http://php.net/str_replace for details.

Answer (score 2):

[str_replace manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

`$body` will receive the string on `$template` after all the occurrences of `'%content%'` being replaced by the value on `$leftcol`.

```
<?php
// Provides: <body text='black'>
$body = str_replace("%content%", "black", "<body text='%content%'>");
?>
```